# Template error in YAML Pipeline - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to build reusable pipeline and basic architecure is -

I have multiple application repositories (**appRepo1, appRepo2,..**) and all of them having their yaml pipeline for example (appRepo1.yml, appRepo2.yml,..)

These app pipelines will call common pipeline(common.yml) which is in different repository (**CommonRepo**).

The common pipeline(common.yml) will be responsible to call other template pipeline(Scanning.yml in ScanRepo,Infra.yml in InfraRepo ) which are in different repositories.

> Basically I want to keep application's pipeline YAML to be very thin

. I don't want to call different templates of different repository from application pipeline. Instead Common template yaml of common repository should templates from various repository.

**appRepo.yml**

```
   name: "$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)"

trigger: none
resources:
  repositories: 
  -  repository: CommonPipeline
     type: GIT
     name: CommonPipeline
     ref: "dev"
  
extends:
 template: common.yml@CommonPipeline
```

***common.yml in CommonRepo***

```
resources:
  repositories: 
    - repository: InfraRepo
      type: GIT
      name: "InfraRepo"
      ref: "dev"
    - repository: ScanRepo
      type: GIT
      name: "ScanRepo"
      ref: "dev"


variables:
        - template: Pipeline/vars/app-var.yaml

stages:
        - template: Pipeline/stages/scanning.yml@ScanRepo
        - template: Pipeline/stages/infra.yml@InfraRepo
```

Is it possible to put (resources -> repositories) in both appRepo.yml and common.yml ? I am getting an error when I run appRepo1 pipeline(appRepo.yml)  if i keep resources section in common.yml.

Error is -

> Internal error reading the template. Expected a scalar,a sequence,or a
> mapping

Comment: Your YAML is malformed. Is this exactly how it's formatted in your repository? If so, carefully check your YAML for indentation issues.

Comment: @DanielMann Fixed those, my question is can we keep (resources -> repositories) in both root yaml & template yaml? If i remove resources section from template yaml, no error but if i put resources section,i am getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have `resources > repositories` in both root and template YAML due to the [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) limitations in Azure Pipelines. This would cause a duplication of the `resources` section within the compiled YAML pipeline which is not valid.

So, you would need to add the repositories in the `appRepo.yml` template. If you are worried about exploitation of the templates, you can check [Security through templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops)

Also check out how you can [enhance pipeline security using resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/about-resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-resources-to-enhance-security)

Comment: I want to have application pipelines having minimum code. application pipelines just to need to call common pipelines which does all the various job.

Comment: Your idea of using `common.yml` is just fine but having the other templates in different repos doesn't look right. You could just keep `scanning.yml` and `infra.yml` in the `CommonPipeline` repository. Think of it as a centralized repo that's hosts all your generic templates that might have stages, steps or jobs.